# matlab: error with subsref

Tags: matlab

I am getting an error with:

```
b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(mag.*subsref(cross(u{1},x), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {':',':',3})) ),r,'UniformOutput',false);

??? Error using ==> subsref
The "subs" field for the subscript argument to SUBSREF and SUBSASGN must be a cell or character array.

Error in ==> cellcross>@(x)nansum(mag.*subsref(cross(u{1},x),struct('type','()','subs',{':',':',3}))) at 2
    b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(mag.*subsref(cross(u{1},x), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {':',':',3})) ),r,'UniformOutput',false);

Error in ==> cellcross at 2
    b = cellfun(@(x) nansum(mag.*subsref(cross(u{1},x), struct('type', '()', 'subs', {':',':',3})) ),r,'UniformOutput',false);
```

can anyone tell me why?

I am using Matlab 2011.

Comment: Can you give a minimal working example?

Answer (score 5):

If you call struct with a cell array as one of the fields, you get an array of structs where the contents of that cell array are distributed over the elements. This happens in `struct('type', '()', 'subs', {':',':',3})`.

I once wrote some code to get around this "feature":

```
function newStruct = structWithCell(varargin)
  % Constructs a structure with cell variables as MATLAB would make a struct
  % array by using the equivalent struct() call
  % Setting values to cell() straight away doesn't work unfortunately
  % as MATLAB(R) interprets structs with cell values as a cell array of structs.
  assert(mod(nargin,2)==0,'An even number of arguments is expected');
  newStruct = struct();
  keys      = varargin(1:2:end-1);
  values    = varargin(2:2:end);
  for iKV = 1:numel(keys)
      newStruct.(keys{iKV}) = values{iKV};
  end
end
```

If you replace your call to `struct` with a call to a the function above, it should work without a problem.

Alternatively, you can also change that part to `struct('type', '()', 'subs', {{':',':',3}})`. That way, you pass a cell array containing a single cell array. This will get you what you want as well.

Comment: just tried your alternative suggestion (as I haven't quite got my head around the function you have created yet). the alternative solution results in the same error. will try your function next. thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, that function `structWithCell` takes almost the same arguments as `struct`. It just iterates over its arguments and adds them to a freshly created struct, without any special behavior for cell arrays (which is treated specially by `struct`).

Comment: The easiest way to get around this struct with cell argument is to use double curly bracets: `struct('type','()','subs',{{':',':',3}})`

Comment: @Shai: that is indeed a nice work-around. You should post it as a solution.

Comment: @Shai: I'm not that awake this morning as apparently, I also mentioned that work-around back when I wrote the answer.